# How to create trigger in SQLite to update table with values from another table in memory database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I have SQLite database and mostly the same scheme in ":memory:" database. I create first, then attach second (memory). And I need to update table in on-disk database with values from table located in-memory database. I created trigger like:

```
create temporary trigger trg after update of _flushMem on mem.tbl "
begin
update tbl set
version = old.version,
...;
update tbl set
...;
end;
```

(there are 2 steps of update, so I have 2 "update" statements. OK. I have special field `_flushMem` which I use to run trigger with SQL statement like: `update mem.tbl set _flushMem=1`. As I understand, SQLite supports triggers between 2 databases with some limitations (but I update current database, not attached). Test shows that trigger does not run. Never. How to write and to launch such trigger?

Comment: Please provide a suitably tailored toy database. Either by providing several lines of "create table ..." and "insert into ..." or, more conveniently, by showing the `.dump` from SQLite command line tool. Add the query which you want to trigger the desired update. Show the desired updated table content, highlighting the intended change.

Comment: Temp triggers only fire on the connection on which they are created. Other commands when run on other connections don't see temp trigger.

Comment: I have 2 connections: for on-disk and for in-mem databases. But 1st (on-disk) attaches 2nd. And "communication "between" them works fine: I select data from attached, delete, update... Trigger is created in 1st - on-disk, because trigger have to modify on-disk data. But must be fired when I update "magic" field `_flushMem` in table in-memory database. It's not principle for me, trigger can be set on the same table/field but of on-disk database. But in this case, I don't know how to get access to data from attached (in-mem) database: I use syntax "old.someField", with suppose that `old` is mem

Comment: @Yunnosch: unfortunately, most actions happen on client-side, and I can not extract SQL from there. Imagine 2 absolutely the same tables. But one is on-disk db, another - in-mem db. And there is `_flushMem` field. I try to fire the trigger by updating it in in-mem db's table. Trigger does not run bcz nothing changes in on-disk table.